# Is there an DAX code to get the values between two integers and then the corresponding value for it?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want the values in between the years mentioned in the image and get their equivalent sales qty.

The sample data is:

[image]

Sample Data

For ex: If I select 2005 in the slicer, I should get the qty ordered as 4+5+6 =15 in the new column or as a measure.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
BetweenRange =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Sales Qty] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table'[Start Year], 'Table'[End Year] ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'YourFilterTable'[Year] ) >= 'Table'[Start Year]
            && SELECTEDVALUE ( 'YourFilterTable'[Year] ) <= 'Table'[End Year]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a variable to read in the slicer value:

```
SumQuantity =
VAR SelectedYear = SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer[Year] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Sales[Sales qty] ),
        Sales[Start year] <= SelectedYear,
        Sales[end Year] >= SelectedYear
    )
```